# Array of abstract type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm quite new with typescript and I'm facing an issue in the app i'm developping.

```
export abstract class DiskElement{
    id:string;
    filename:string;
}

export class File extends DiskElement{
    size:number;
}

export class Directory extends DiskElement{
    children:DiskElement[];
}

export class User{
    shares:DiskElement[];
}
```

My issue is when I load my users from a Json file, it says that size property doesn't belong to type DiskElement.

I fixed my issue by declaring shares/children as (File | Directory )[] but I don't feel like this solution is maintenable in the long run. I have multiple arrays of 'parent' classes in my application and having to modify each declaration of collections each time I add a new subType is gonna be exhausting.

I'm pretty sure there's a very simple & nice solution.

How I load it is something like that :

```
users : User =  {
    shares: 
    [
        {
           id:"{123-12312312-12312}",
           filename:"test.jpg",
           size:123123000
        },
        {
           id:"{222-2222222-22222}",
           filename:"testFolder",
           children:[{...},{...}]
         }
   ]};
```

It's in a mock 'dataset' , but it doesn't compile with the error I explained above, size isn't a property of DiskElement.

Changing User to :

```
export class User{
    shares:(File|Directory)[];
}
```

This works, and as @Jonas Wilms pointed out I could define a new union type that is File|Directory and make sure to update that type whenever I subclass DiskElement in the future, but I still feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: I posted my answer second guessing your problem, but I think it would be beneficial to show how you are loading your data from the JSON file.

Comment: `DiskElement` does not contain a `size` property, `File` does. When you use `extends`, it is saying that `File` inherits everything from `DiskElement`, and `DiskElement` remains unchanged. I think you are thinking that extends means it will push properties to the parent, which is why it is causing confusion. [Here's a link to the docs with examples of how this works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

Comment: It sounds like what you're actually trying to do is pull `File` and `Directory` into `DiskElement`, which you can do with [mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html). Although maybe not exactly, since the added properties will be optional depending on the type?

Comment: @mhodges i'd rather say that the OP is trying to uptype

Answer (score 0):

You could just make `size` an optional property:

```
 export abstract class DiskElement{
    id:string;
    filename:string;
    size?: number;
 }
```

Or if there are multiple possible subclasses, e.g. `File` and `Blob`:

```
export abstract class DiskElement{
   id:string;
   filename:string;
}

 class File extends DiskElement {
  size: number;
 }

 class Blob extends DiskElement {
   length: number;
 }
```

then you could use a union type to type something on the disk:

```
 type Data = File | Blob;
```

that way you can use `Data` everywhere and add new types easily. To then access the size you have to add a typeguard:

```
 var sth: Data = new File();

 if(sth instanceof File) { // sth: Data -> File
   console.log(sth.size); // works
 }
```

Comment: Your second solution is what I did, but it still doesn't make sense to me.

File is a DiskElement to begin with. Why can't I add it to an array of DiskElement is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out...

In javascript there wasn't a huge difference between :

```
var users = { prop1:"zzz", prop2:"aaaa"}; //(json without quotes)
var users = JSON.parse(json);
```

Turns out it's obviously not true in typescript.
So my example above becomes :

```
users : User = JSON.parse(`
{
    shares: 
    [
        {
           id:"{123-12312312-12312}",
           filename:"test.jpg",
           size:123123000
        },
        {
           id:"{222-2222222-22222}",
           filename:"testFolder",
           children:[{...},{...}]
         }
    ]
}`);
```

And this way it works as expected.